# How to add libraries to c code in XCode 4.4

Tags: c, xcode, xcode4

I am having some trouble adding library path inside XCode.  I am writing C code.

I have both my code and the library I want to add.  But I have trouble adding the library, say a math library I want to use.  I think the path is not set correctly.  I do not know how to set paths inside XCode.

Would anyone know or have an example of how to add libraries to a C code?  I am using the current version: XCode 4.4.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just copy the dylib to /usr/lib and the headers to /usr/include? That way GCC (or Clang) can find it without trouble.

Comment: @H2CO3 I see.  It looked a lot like Eclipse for Java, so, I was looking for an option to set the path.  What do you mean by headers?  I am confused.

Comment: @userXXX I meant the header files.

Comment: @H2CO3 so, my understanding is that: header files=libraries.  And I am copying the library I downloaded (dylib is the technical term?) to usr/include.  I was told that I have to go to root directory, also use sudo in terminal to copy files.  Is that necessary?

Comment: Also, was it recommended not to use /usr/include to avoid messing something up?

Comment: There is no dylib, the library I am trying to use is gsl/gsl_math.h

Comment: @userXXX is this a C++ library?

Comment: @H2CO3 it's a C library.  http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Comment: @userXXX **if so, then there is a dylib.** C libraries aren't header-only.

Comment: how should I copy it to the directory?  Do I have to use Terminal?

Comment: Just on terminology: a "library" may be shipped in a single header, it's just unusual unless all the functions are inline.  In C++ it's more common because templated implementation needs to be instantiated by the client code, so must be exposed to the including translation unit.  Still, from a sys-admin perspective a library normally means a `.a` or `.so` file rather than a `.h`.